# programmatically check if sharepoint installed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, stsadm

I'm developing an application which test if SharePoint is installed correctly, with `stsadm` and PowerShell access.

I wonder if there is a specified `stsadm` or PowerShell command or a specified C# code I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query `Windows Registry` is probably the most reliable way to detect if SharePoint installed (Visual Studio uses this technique).
Please follow the article [How To: Detect the Installed SKU of SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff721969.aspx) for more details. It contains code sample that demonstrates how to retrieve the registry key of the installed SKU of SharePoint Server 2010.

### PowerShell

[Detect installed SharePoint 2010 or 2013 products using PowerShell](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Detect-installed-dd79a8ed)

> This PowerShell function returns a hash table to the pipeline
>   containing SharePoint 2010 or 2013 products and the SharePoint Build
>   Version installed on your server.
>
> This function has been verified to work with:
>
> All SharePoint 2010 and 2013 versions

Comment: Imen, i'm glad it helped :)